# Laravel check form submit value

Tags: laravel, forms, controller, submit

Hi I was trying to use form to submit a value to search in the database,however I could not make it work. Can anyone help with this?

```
<form action="/comp1230/assignments/assignment2/public/search" method="post">
<h2>Please enter the keywords you want to search:</h2>
<input id="search"type=text name="searchcontent">
<input type="submit" value='Search'>
</form>
```

Above is the welcome.blade.php form, I want to have this submited value to be used in my controller,code is shown below:

```
    public function search()
{

     $search = Input::get('searchcontent');
     $results=Records::paginate(5);
     $records=[];
     foreach($results as $result)
     if(!in_array($search,$result)){
        continue;
     }else{
        array_push($records,$result);
     }

    return view('home',['records'=>$records]);
}
```

route:

```
Route::post('/search', 'RecordController@search');
```

but what i got is

```
419
Sorry, your session has expired. Please refresh and try again.

GO HOME
```

Please help, thanks a lot!

Comment: you can try to add @csrf after opening your form

Comment: Thanks, but how to handle the data after submission?
$search = Input::get('searchcontent'); will this work?

Comment: you should accept the request object as a parameter to your method search

Comment: Use request object https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#retrieving-input

Comment: public function search(Request $request){
}

Comment: Thanks,I have put it into the function parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel pagination only works with get parameters.

and after pagination, array conversion takes miscellaneous concepts

the following example illustrates this concept

```
          1. Get data from database
          2. Filter data corresponding search_content using in_array (in_array accepts data array only and not for objects)
          3. Perform manual pagination and display records
```

Code for RecordsController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator as Paginator;

use App\Records;

class RecordController extends Controller
{
    // Show Entry Form
    public function index()
    {
        return view('search_entry');

    }

    public function search(Request $request)
    {

         $search = Input::get('searchcontent');

         $results=Records::get()->toArray();
         $records=[];

         foreach($results as $result)       //in_array accepts array only
         {

            if(in_array($search, $result))
            {
                array_push($records, $result);
            }

         }

        $page = $request->page; // current page for pagination

        // manually slice array of product to display on page
        $perPage = 5;
        $offset = ($page-1) * $perPage;
        $new_record = array_slice($records, $offset, $perPage);

        // your pagination 
        $new_record = new Paginator($new_record, count($records), $perPage, $page, ['path'  => $request->url(),'query' => $request->query()]);

        return view('home',['records' => $new_record]);
    }  
}
```

Code for search_entry.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>LaravelTest</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="{{url('search')}}" >
            <h2>Please enter the keywords you want to search:</h2>
            <input id="search"type=text name="searchcontent">
            <input type="submit" value='Search'>
        </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

code for home.blade.php (resultant view php)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>LaravelTest</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>SEARCH CONTENT</h3>
        <table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>ID</td> <td>NAME</td> <td>AGE</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                    foreach($records as $record)
                    {
                        echo "<tr><td>".$record['id']."</td><td>".$record['name']."</td><td>".$record['age']."</td></tr>";
                    }
                ?>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            {{ $records->links('pagination::bootstrap-4') }}


    </body>
</html>
```

Add the following Routing code in Web.php

```
Route::get('search_entry','RecordController@index');
Route::get('search','RecordController@search');
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix the exception by adding the csrf token to your form

```
<form action="/comp1230/assignments/assignment2/public/search" method="post">
    @csrf
```